# Is the image of a measurable set by a measurable function measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, abstract-algebra, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ and $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$ be measurable spaces and $f:\mathsf{X}\to\mathsf{Y}$ be a measurable function. Is this true?
$$
\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{X} \implies f(\mathsf{A})\in\mathcal{Y}
$$

> If not, what extra conditions do I need to add?

I know that given $\mathsf{B}\in\mathcal{Y}$ one has $f^{-1}(\mathsf{B})\in\mathcal{X}$ but not the reverse.

##### Remarks

Not sure if it would help but I could potentially assume that $\mathcal{Y}$ is countably-generated and contains all singleton sets. Also, I am mainly interested in the application of this to probability theory, so I am happy to assume that $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$ is a probability space so that $f$ is a random variable.

Comment: Not is not true. This is in part the study of analytic sets, Suslin schemes etc.

Comment: Not necessarily. Take $X=Y=\Omega$ where $\Omega$ has a few elements, $\mathcal{X}=2^{\Omega}, \mathcal{Y}=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ and $f:X\to Y$ the identity function on $\Omega$.

Comment: for your initial question - as an analogy... have you considered that the image of an open set by a continuous function is not necessarily open?

Comment: @OliverDiaz what if $\mathcal{Y}$ is countably generated and contains all singleton sets?

Comment: If your measures are $\sigma$-finite, whatever $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$ is, you can take $X = [0,1] \times Y$, consider a product measure of Lebesgue and what you had on $Y$, take $S$ not measurable in $Y$, and $f : (x,y) \mapsto y$ the projection on $Y$.

Then $\{0\} \times S$ is measurable (with measure $0$), but its projection $S$ is not.

I don't know if you can always choose $X$ (for a counterexample) given $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$, or what conditions on $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ would ensure you can find a proper $Y$ for a counterexample

Comment: @Euler_Salter: Even if $Y$ is $\mathbb{R}$ (or any Polish space for that matter). All this is not a trivial thing to be discussed thoroughly in an MSE posting. Fortunately, all this business of analytic sets, Suslin scheme and the like, appear now as part of books on measure theory. I nice treatment is in Cohn, D. Measure theory, Birkhuaser for example. Results of from this theory have many applications in Statistics and Stochastic Analysis. For example the notion of hitting times of arbitrary measurable sets.

Comment: Do you know the answer to your question in the most basic setting? **Q**.  *Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function.  Show that $f$ maps Lebesgue measurable sets to Lebesgue measurable sets if and only if $f$ satisfies Lusin's condition (N).*  That gives you some perspective on the problem.

Comment: By the way (a supplement to my other comment) if the set of points at which a continuous function $f$  is  differentiable has measure zero, then there exists a measurable set $E$ such that $f(E)$ is not measurable.  In particular every continuous nowhere differentiable function fails to map all measurable sets to measurable sets.  You can say, therefore, *most* continuous functions are like this.  Not rare at all.